# Tree traversal and concatenation crashes in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory

There is a random tree generator and I have to concatenate the values of the tree based on child traversals. For example if I have

```
com ----- org------net---
           |
           mom---dad---son
                        |
                       good
```

I would want the string "goodsonorg"

```
struct trie_node *going = root;   // this gets the root of the tree
char* joiner = NULL;             //using this to join the previous part

char *lastOne = (char *)(malloc(going->strlen+1000)); //setting safe buffer

while(going->next != NULL || going->children != NULL) {

    while(going->next){         // always go as right as possible
        going = going->next;
    }

    if(going->children){      //traverse down to child

        if(joiner == NULL) { // traverse from root (previous will be null)

             printf(" first key is: \n");
             joiner = (char *)(malloc(going->strlen)+100);
             strncpy(joiner,going->key, going->strlen+1);       
             puts(joiner);
        }

        else{
            printf(" \n We need to concatenate: \n");
            going = going->children; // go down

            strncpy(lastOne, going->key, going->strlen); // get the current key in last
            puts(lastOne);
            printf(" with the previous one to get: \n ");
            strcat(lastOne, joiner); // attach the joiner to it.

            strncpy(joiner, lastOne, strlen(joiner)+strlen(lastOne)); // then update the joiner
            puts(lastOne);
            }
```

By the end of this block of code I should have my concatenated string in lastOne, however I get a segfault for some reason. I am not sure why. I am allocating safe big buggers because realloc was giving me errors. Is there anything obvious that I am missing here? The tree traversal definitely works.

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-obfuscation).

Comment: I think the format got messed up in copy pasting

Comment: Either way; proper formatting attracts people to your question and encourages them to help you.

Comment: sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with `malloc(going->strlen)+100`. You are getting an address from the heap with `malloc()` then adding 100 to that address for some reason, and explicitly casting it to force it to work. (I suggest looking at [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).) Such pointer arithmetic doesn't make sense. This will surely cause you to read or write in the wrong place later, causing a segfault.

Instead of guessing what an appropriate string allocation size should be, keep track of how big it is, and expand it as needed (see [`realloc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)).